# E-mail privacy in HTML

Tags: html, email, privacy

How should I solve the e-mail privacy issue on the webpage, so it is not displayed in plain text in HTML code?

Malicious bots scrape the web in search of email addresses and plain text email addresses are more likely to be spammed.

Comment: what have you tried? I'm sure a search on your preferred search engine should at least give some results?

Comment: Install a spam filter. Problem solved?

Comment: You could use a purely `CSS` method, utilising the `:after` selector. http://www.marcofolio.net/css/hiding_email_addresses_from_spambots_using_css.html Although the only downside is that the user can't select this email address. So in terms of usability, this won't be the best option.

Comment: Type 'at' instead of @, a user can just change that part easily

Comment: Good idea, but what do you mean by that "the user can't select this email address"?

Comment: @NickR Given that that page states that "IE doesn't support `:after`" yet, I'd say it's out of date and spambots have learned about that particular trick by now ;)

Comment: @TheKolanN - check the demo, http://www.marcofolio.net/images/stories/programming/css/hiding_mail/hiding_mail_using_css.html you'll notice how you can't actually select the text, but it still displays, as it is `CSS` generated content.

Comment: @NickR I see right now. Thanks for the explanation. But is there a way to make it clickable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe way to display email address and contact number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359202/safe-way-to-display-email-address-and-contact-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of ways that you can do this:

- spell the email out 'info at domain dot com'
- create an image of the email address
- use a contact form with additional anti-spam measures such as captcha

  Unfortunately. most of these methods make it difficult for end users (especially the first two)

Comment: I think this is mostly directed at email address input - I could be wrong but I believe the OP is asking how to display an email without getting it scraped.

Comment: I agree... There is no best method, each one of them has some drawbacks...

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best way is to require the user to solve a CAPTCHA of some kind, and then when they succeed you should give them the email in plain text.

In particular, this allows users to copy-paste it into their email client, without the risk of mis-typing. Additionally, with the right CAPTCHA, this allows users with disabilities to contact you as well.

That said, you can keep your address completely hidden by having a contact form. In this way, it will be your server sending you the email on behalf of the user, and they will only ever know your address if you reply to them.

Comment: I think he means email addresses in the page content.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a common method is to create an image with the email text within it.

Algorithms to read text from an image are a lot more complex (and error prone) than simple web scraping ones!

Edited to expand to include the details given in the comments.
It's important that this work be done server side, any manipulation done in javascript is likely to include the email address somewhere in the page's source - which any web scraper will have access to. Better to include an image with no reference to the image at all in it's url.

Comment: Good idea, but should not we try to use some JavaScript instead?

Comment: You can increase that complexity a bit with `address at site dot com`, instead of `address@site.com`.

Comment: @ajp15243 it's a nice halfway step yes

Comment: @Liath I meant for the text in the image, to further complicate image text analysis.

Comment: @TheKolanN comverting via javascript is a bad idea because any webscraper would have access to that JS too. Having the email in the page source at all puts it at risk.

Comment: The web scraper can also get the page source without executing JavaScript in the first place (many do already), thereby leaving your plaintext address exposed if you try converting on the fly with JavaScript.